# Query for searching a specific date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, there is a [date range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html) and fuzzy date query, however I don't see a query for querying a specific date.

Do you know if that type of query exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following mapping:

```
"properties": {
    "myDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dd-MM-yyyy"
    }
}
```

The query for searching the exact date would be:

```
"query": {
    "term": {
        "myDate": {
            "value": "10-10-2010"
        }
    }
}
```